# SwiftUI view does not resize despite automaticDimension in UIKit TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am reusing a SwiftUI view in a UIKit TableViewCell but the cell is not resizing accordingly despite having `automaticDimension` set.

Code:

```
class TestController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.title = "Test"
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.register(TestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
        cell.title = "Title \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}

class TestCell: UITableViewCell  {
    var host: UIHostingController<TestView>?

    var title: String? {
        didSet {
            if let title = title {
                if host == nil {
                    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView(text: title))
                    host = hostingController
                    
                    let hostingView = hostingController.view
                    hostingView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    contentView.addSubview(hostingView ?? UIView())
                    hostingView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
                    hostingView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                    hostingView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                    hostingView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
                } else {
                    host?.rootView = TestView(text: title)
                }
                
                setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Text("Subtitle")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Notice the exaggerated constant of 40 inside the didSet method, the code seems to push the content downwards correctly, but it does not expand the height of the cell.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing the same issue

Comment: @StevePayne unfortunately no, I ended up rewriting the views in uikit